# Userspace interrupt for gpio pins that don't have edge sysfs

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, interrupt, gpio, libgpiod

In my platform, there is a PCA9555 CMOS device which has 16 GPIO pins and a separate INT pin for interrupts. So long, my application was periodically reading a particular gpio pin. I need to change it to an interrupt driven way. From the spec :  *It has an open-drain interrupt pin which is activated when one of the 16 port pins changes state and the pin is configured as an input. A pin configured as an output cannot cause an interrupt.*

None of the 16 pins have interrupt support themselves and I don't see `edge` sysfs in /sys/class/gpio/gpio/[pin_no]. So `poll()` on `value` file is not blocking. And I infer from the spec that an interrupt would be triggered to CPU if state of any of the input pins change. How do I catch this interrupt in userspace?

I see in `gpiolib-cdev.c` about line events.
`static irqreturn_t lineevent_irq_handler(int irq, void *p)`

Can I use `/dev/gpiochip<n>` character device  and `poll()` for interrupts? or is this only supported for a gpio pin that supports interrupt?

Comment: Do you have that line connected somewhere? Do you describe that connection properly in the DT? Do you enabled IRQ chip (interrupt-controller) in the DT? Suggestion: look at the tons of the existing examples inside Linux kernel source tree (_arch/*/boot/dts_ or so).

Comment: @0andriy Yes I've that line connected to a GPIO pin of Intel Xeon. There is no DT. ACPI should be handling it. It turns out that the particular GPIO pin of Intel ICH isn't an interrupt pin and I won't be able to get interrupted.

Comment: @0andriy In case the hardware design were such that the INT pin of pca9555 is connected to a CPU pin which would support interrupt, will I be seeing 'edge' sysfs for all input pins of PCA9555 ?

Comment: You see, it's very important detail that your Q missed, i.e. x86 + ACPI (and where is the description on how you actually enumerate that IO expander in the OS?). On top of that, using deprecated (sysfs) interface is discouraged. Anyway, have you checked schematics and how INT pin is connected? I have a few Intel boards (i.e. Galileo Gen 2, Edison) which use that IO expander with IRQ without any issues.

Comment: @0andriy Yes I checked the schematics and INT pin is connected to GPIO_SUS17 of CPU which isn't an interrupt. I wonder what if I connect it to an interrupt pin, say GPIO_SUS6. In that case, whether the gpio-pca953x driver which handles the interrupt along with the gpio driver library would make life simpler by providing 'edge' sysfs or for that matter poll() implementation for line event for every input pin of pca9555? E.g. I configure pins 1,2 and 3 as inputs. Can I poll() for line events on these pins?

Comment: Still you are speaking cryptic language. What CPU / SoC you are using? Can you share piece(s) of the schematics that is (are) relevant to the IO expander connection? What the alternative pins you may use? These above are about HW. On SW part, what kernel version you are using? Have you enabled all necessary drivers? How you describe your IO expander that OS may enumerate it? You still kept silent... We may not make a progress without clarification.